# Do solar eclipse paper glasses need to list both the ISO and CE stamp to be compliant or is the ISO sufficient?

Tags: telescope, solar-eclipse

I purchased them at the checkout at Walmart. They are Manufactured by American Paper Optics, LLC. Visionscientific.com ISO 12312-2.

However I don't see the CE on the glasses. Are they still OK?  The reason I even bring this up at all is that I read in the news there are counterfeit glasses and Walmart was listed as a potential source.

I do not know what it means for eclipse glasses to be counterfeit. Does that mean there may be a pair of paper glasses like mine that says visionscientific.com ISO 12312-2 but is not  or does that mean that it would be missing the ISO or has a different one. So that is what brought the CE question to my attention after I read the news article.

Comment: If they're by American Paper Optics they're good.

Comment: CE is a mark required for goods in the EU (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking). It does not indicate any conformance  to standards as determined by an independent testing laboratory.

Comment: FWIW, Fred Espenak, aka Mr Eclipse, endorses eclipse glasses from American Paper Optics. https://eclipsewise.com/eclipse.html

Comment: Thank you PM 2Ring. 30 days to the eclipse. I hope it is not cloudy. My area has about 3 min of totality.